# Add a sequence number for each element in a group using an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have an Oracle table with the following data:

```
ID          VALUE
10           A
10           B
10           C
20           A1
30           C1
30           D1
```

I want to do a *group by* based on the ID column and print a new column with the sequence number within each group.

The output would look like this:

```
ID          VALUE     GROUPSEQ
10           A           1
10           B           2
10           C           3
20           A1          1
30           C1          1
30           D1          2
```

Can this be done using an Oracle SQL query, without creating a temporary table?

Comment: Why you have tagged this ques with mysql and oracle both. Please remove mysql.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need [ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

```
SELECT ID, VALUE, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY value) GROUPSEQ
FROM myTable
```

Comment: Great !! It Worked. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:-

```
 SELECT ID, VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY VALUE) "GROUPSEQ"
 FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: Any specific reason this answer should be accepted over the other one which same and was given 3 minutes earlier than you?

Comment: I was saying because user doesn't select any of the answer as selected. If user selects other one. Then also i dont have any problem. Because selecting the answer help other people in future as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a query for you. I hope it will solve your problem :

```
(SELECT t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER ()
    OVER (PARTITION BY t.id
          ORDER BY t.id)
       seq_no
  FROM test t);
```

Check [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6ad4/1/0)

Comment: I think you want `ORDER BY t.value`

Comment: No it should be order t.id

Comment: if you order by t.id first group have `10` three time, so no really order

Comment: what if the data into table is unordered

Comment: You can see the OP result is order by value. if you order by id you can have any random result.